# Mysql combine columns if not null

Tags: mysql

I know that I can combine multiple columns in mysql by doing:

```
SELECT CONCAT(zipcode, ' - ', city, ', ', state) FROM Table;
```

However, if one of the fields is `NULL` then the entire value will be `NULL`. So to prevent this from happening I am doing:

```
SELECT CONCAT(zipcode, ' - ', COALESE(city,''), ', ', COALESCE(state,'')) FROM Table;
```

However, there still can be situation where the result will look something like this:

```
zipcode-, ,
```

Is there a way in MySQL to only have to comma and the hyphen if the next columns are not `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a native function that will do this called Concat with Separator (`concat_ws`)!

Specifically, it seems that what you would need is:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' - ',zipcode, NULLIF(CONCAT_WS(', ',city,state),'')) FROM TABLE;
```

This should account for all of the null cases you allude to.

However, it is important to note that a blank string (`''`) is different than a `NULL`. If you want to address this in the state/city logic you would add a second `NULLIF` check inside the second `CONCAT_ws` for the case where a city or a state would be blank strings. This will depend on the database's regard for the blank field and whether you are entering true `NULLS` into your database or checking the integrity of the blank data before you use it. Something like the following might be slightly more robust:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' - ', zipcode, NULLIF(CONCAT_WS(', ', NULLIF(city, ''), NULLIF(state, '')), '')) FROM TABLE;
```

For more, check out the native documentation on `concat_ws()` here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this

```
Set @zipcode := '12345';
Set @city := NULL;
Set @state := NULL;
SELECT CONCAT(@zipcode, ' - ', COALESCE(@city,''), ', ', COALESCE(@state,''));
```

Result: 12345 - ,

```
SELECT CONCAT(@zipcode, IF(@city is NULL,'', CONCAT(' - ', @city)), IF(@state is NULL,'', CONCAT(', ',@state)))
```

Result 12345

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the output of the separators conditional on the following values being non-NULL. For example:

```
SELECT CONCAT(zipcode,
              CASE WHEN city IS NOT NULL OR state IS NOT NULL THEN ' - '
                   ELSE ''
              END,
              COALESCE(city, ''),
              CASE WHEN city IS NOT NULL AND state IS NOT NULL THEN ', '
                   ELSE ''
              END,
              COALESCE(state, '')
              ) AS address
FROM `Table``
```

Output (for my demo)

```
address
12345 - San Francisco, CA
67890 - Los Angeles 
34567 - AL
87654
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=137c93cfedf371b68a31406831903d21)